# How to boot my laptop from USB pendrive with Fedora

Tags: linux, boot, usb, fedora, usb-flash-drive

I have a laptop with Windows 11 installed. I wanted to change the OS to Linux, specifically Fedora. I installed Fedora Media Writer and created a bootable pendrive (Fedora Workstation 38). I changed the boot priority to the pendrive and restarted the laptop. (Bios - American Megatrends 5.13). After that, however, it took a long time to start, and when it did, the Fedora installation did not start, but Windows did open. I searched many topics and found the following: secure boot - disabled (it didn't help); fast boot -disabled (didn't help); quiet boot - disabled (didn't help). I don't have other options from other topics or they are named differently, so I wasn't able to check them. Anyone know what will help?

Comment: Most likely a defective build of the USB. See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-and-using-a-live-installation-image/ for troubleshooting and other ways to make the bootable USB. Also, try Rufus: https://rufus.ie/en/

Comment: That doesn't work